# show a maximum number of characters and a button that when clicked shows the full text in the description of the blog tag pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Hi I just want that when I fill a tag description on my wordpress blog, on front end appears like my woocommerce tags descriptions like here (https://www.regalizfunwear.es/etiqueta-producto/cinturones-arcade/) showing just a custom number of characters and a link to show all description.

I just found the code that is working on product tags but I dont know how to use it for blog tags like (https://www.regalizfunwear.es/tag/moda/):

```css
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header{
    text-align: left;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap{
    display: flex;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap.has-content{
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap > .term-thumbnail{
    padding-right: 2rem;
    flex-basis: 17rem;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap > .term-thumbnail > img{
    display: block;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap .term-description{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    flex: 1;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap .term-description > *:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px){
    .woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap{
        display: block;
    }

    .woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description-wrap > .term-thumbnail{
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-description *{
    text-align: left !important;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-read-more{
    display: none;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-read-more:not(:checked) ~ .term-description{
    height: 20rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-products-header .term-read-more:not(:checked) ~ .term-description:after{
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "Leer más";
    display: block;
    font-size: .9em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', function () {
    if (!(is_product_taxonomy() && 0 === absint(get_query_var('paged')))) {
        return;
    }
    $term = get_queried_object();
    if (!$term) {
        return;
    }
//    add_filter('woocommerce_format_content', function ($text) {
//        $text = wpautop($text);
//        $text = str_replace(['<p>', '<p >', '</p>'], ['', '', '<br><br>'], $text);
//        return $text;
//    });
    ?>
    <label class="term-description-wrap <?php echo $term->description ? 'has-content' : '' ?>">
    <?php
}, 1);

add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', function () {
    if (!(is_product_taxonomy() && 0 === absint(get_query_var('paged')))) {
        return;
    }
    $term = get_queried_object();
    if (!$term) {
        return;
    }
    $thumbnail_id = absint(get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true));
    if (!$thumbnail_id) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="term-thumbnail">
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail') ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}, 5);

add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', function () {
    if (!(is_product_taxonomy() && 0 === absint(get_query_var('paged')))) {
        return;
    }
    $term = get_queried_object();
    if (!$term) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <input class="term-read-more" type="checkbox">
    <?php
}, 6);

add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', function () {
    if (!(is_product_taxonomy() && 0 === absint(get_query_var('paged')))) {
        return;
    }
    $term = get_queried_object();
    if (!$term) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    </label>
    <?php
}, 100);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, do you want a string of text to cut off after a certain number of characters? I know you can do that with CSS `overflow:hidden;` and `max-width: $declared_amount;`. Or you can also do that with line clamp. I typically use lineclamp for all my excerpts.

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
```

You can also make a javascript function on checkbox click and toggle a class that removes the lineclamp if you want it to show when selected. In Jquery if would look something like this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("expand-clamp");
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I update the details becouse I found the code that was working for product tags